# Grid view is not displaying in asp.net web page

Tags: html, asp.net, css, vb.net, web

I am building my website every thing is going good ,but when I run my website the grid view doesn't appear ,, please would any one help me how to fix the problem and let the grid view appear on the page

here is the aspx code :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Member.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Order.aspx.vb" Inherits="Order" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1"     ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">


     <script type="text/javascript">
         var oldgridcolor;
         function SetMouseOver(element) {
             oldgridcolor = element.style.backgroundColor;
             element.style.backgroundColor = '#ffeb95';
             element.style.cursor = 'pointer';
             element.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
         }
         function SetMouseOut(element) {
             element.style.backgroundColor = oldgridcolor;
             element.style.textDecoration = 'none';
         }
</script>


</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">


  <div style="margin-right: 0cm; margin-left: 4.1cm; height: 679px; background-color: #CC0000; width: 1038px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 109px;">

  <fieldset style="width:230px;">
            <legend style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size: xx-large; color: #FFFF00; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal">Menu<asp:SqlDataSource 
                    ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conStr %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Menu]">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <br />
            </legend>
            <asp:GridView ID="MenuGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
                CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="MealNo" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                Width="990px"   GridLines="None" OnRowDataBound="EmpGridView_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MealNo" HeaderText="MealNo"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MealName" HeaderText="MealName"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Desp" HeaderText="Desp" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MealCateID" HeaderText="MealCateID"/>
                </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
         <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
         <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
         <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
         <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
         <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            </asp:GridView>
            </fieldset>
            </div>        
</asp:Content>
```

vb code :

```
    Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration

Partial Class Order
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            BindEmpGrid()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub BindEmpGrid()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Try
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conStr").ConnectionString)
            Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Menu", con)
            adp.Fill(dt)

            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                MenuGrid.DataSource = dt
                MenuGrid.DataBind()
            Else
                MenuGrid.DataSource = Nothing
                MenuGrid.DataBind()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write("Error Occured: " & ex.ToString())
        Finally
            dt.Clear()
            dt.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Sub EmpGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles MenuGrid.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            e.Row.Attributes("onmouseover") = "javascript:SetMouseOver(this)"
            e.Row.Attributes("onmouseout") = "javascript:SetMouseOut(this)"
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: try to debug and see whether you are getting any data in dt or not

Answer (score 1):

You are not opening the connection anywhere. Open it or better wrap in `Using ... End Using`, Try like this:

```
Using con As New sqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conStr").ConnectionString)
            Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Menu", con)
            adp.Fill(dt)
End Using
```